# Manufactured home joint ownership

Tags: united-states, home-ownership, pennsylvania

If my sister and I own a manufactured home that I live in and pay everything including taxes for, what are my rights to sell or to remove her from the title? Does she forfeit her rights after so long of not paying anything on the home?

Comment: Did you have any sort of written agreement that outlines payment responsibilities of each person?  There are good answers to a very similar question here: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6160/in-a-house-with-shared-ownership-if-one-person-moves-out-and-the-other-assumes

Answer (score 6):

In the US there is not a legal way to remove someone from a title without their consent. The fact that you paid the payments and taxes is irrelevant. It's unfortunate that you feel like you paid more than your fair share; perhaps you can get some relief when you sell the home by getting more than half of the proceeds, but she would have to agree to that in order to sell. Hopefully your relationship is strong enough that it won't be a strain.